# How to run user code on server in different languages?

Tags: server, user-input, execution

I would like to make an application simmilar to CodeFights in that a user is given a set of excercises for which he has to code solutions. I figured out how to take a users JavaScript code and run it on a Node.js server using for example the Function constructor:

```
try {
   var solver = new Function('arg1', 'arg2', bodyAsString);
} catch(e) {
   console.log('Function cannot be parsed');
}
```

Good thing about this approach is that the *solver(...,...)* function now has access to global scope only and not the scope it was made in. Even better one could also combine this with a *[sandbox module](https://github.com/gf3/sandbox)*.

But what is the best approach if I want to use multiple languages - let's say JavaScript, Python and C++. How do I go about solving this problem if I want to give the user a choice of language? Do I write his solution to a file and try to execute it via command line also in some kind of a sandbox mode? Can this even be done if I use Node.js as backend?

Comment: Have you checked https://repl.it/, http://ideone.com/, https://www.codechef.com/ide or other available solutions? Doing what you want in safe way is not trivial - and if you miss something, you open yourself to all kinds of hackers.

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski No not yet - thank you for those. I wasn't even quite sure how to formulate the problem in english to be honest. Wasn't even sure which terms to use / how is it called.